# Website, works in virtual application fails in own site

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-server-2008

I have an asp.net 4 project that during testing  was run inside a virtual application, now I am closer to deployment, I want it in it's own site, however it fails to operate correctly.

I have the site pointed to the same local folder, using the same application pool, and I think with the same permissions and settings.

The odd behavior is hard to explain (not total failure, but parts of the application fail), but suffice to say application fails.

I would consider simply making the site redirect to the working virtual application, however I will be deploying to multi locations, and that will complicate things greatly.

The only think I can think of is that there is something related to the root permissions being different from the virtual application, or some mime/handler or other setting added to the default site that I am unaware of.

I tried exporting both, and comparing the xml files, but I'm pretty green with that tool, so no luck there.

Comment: I have discovered this is related to my use of Session in the code, I do not understand why, but it is definitely related. A quick solution has been to replace Session usage with ViewState, however more data flows between client and server now.

Comment: My eew solution was to make a dynamic redirect page using Environment.MachineName to build to the assumed relative virtual application path.

Comment: Voting to close as "not a real question".  There is no way to answer this without knowing more about your code.  From your comments, it sounds like you've narrowed the problem down to Session issues.  Perhaps now that you have some idea, you could update the question with some details that might help someone help you.